# On hover button showed up but it glitches around when entering

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hover

I want to implement a simple hover animation. A button should appear when a container is hovered. This also works so far, but the button jerks or enters the box uncleanly. Anyone know a better solution?

This is my approach. https://codepen.io/Sofatroll/pen/PoxrYKV

```
<div class="teaser-unter">
  <div class="teaser-img">
    <img src="https://www.landtiere.de/bilder/2022/10/20/91863382/30102822-eichhoernchen-superheld-luft-2iyGCm7LNlBG.jpg" width="500" height="auto"
  </div>
</div>

const teaserImg = document.querySelectorAll('.teaser-img')

teaserImg.forEach((element) => {
  const moreButton = document.createElement('div')
  moreButton.className = 'morebutton'
  moreButton.innerHTML = 'mehr lesen'

  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      moreButton.style.scale = '1'
    }, 100)
    element.appendChild(moreButton)
    moreButton.style.transition = '0.3s'
  })

  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    moreButton.style.transition = '0.3s'
    moreButton.style.scale = '0'
    if (element.contains(moreButton)) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      element.removeChild(moreButton);
    }, 200);
  }
  })

  element.onmousemove = (e) => {
    const x = e.clientX - element.getBoundingClientRect().left - 45 + 'px'
    const y = e.clientY - element.getBoundingClientRect().top - 100 + 'px'

    setTimeout(() => {
      moreButton.style.transition = '0s'
    }, 300)
    moreButton.style.left = x
    moreButton.style.top = y
  }
})
```

Comment: The issue you are seeing is caused by how you set up your transition property. Move your animation configurations to your css, it will help smooth it out, don't try to change your transition values via code.

Comment: @JeffB Nice this was the solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you have time, it would be great to post a "self answer" of your solution in case it helps anybody else.